# What do the pins on this KS0107+KS0108 display do?

Tags: lcd, pins

I got this display on ebay and I have no instructions on how to use it. I can guess what most of them do but I'd rather be sure I know what they all are instead of messing around trying to guess. The ebay page said the screen is a KS0107+KS0108 128x64 display.

[image: photo of screen]

Is there any documentation on what these pins do and which ones I need to connect to my arduino uno to get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[glcd-arduino](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/GLCDks0108) (GLCDv3) is an unofficial Arduino library that supports Graphic LCDs (GLCD) that use the KS0108 (or equivalent) chip.

[image]

Comment: Ah I see there is a diagram there with the numbers 1-20. Is this some kind of standard arrangement for these kinds of LCDs?

Comment: In most cases, yes. Sometimes there are LCDs in which CS1, CS2 (CSEL1, CSEL2 ) have an inverted input.

Comment: This LCD corresponds to Pinout B according to the table.